# Resize parent element with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a styled div with an as h1 its only child element. The text of the h1 changes dynamically via javascript.

When new text is inserted into the h1 tag the height of that h1 is measured then used to change the height of its parent div element.

The parent div however changes to the height of the h1 but including the padding thus causing there to be no actual padding.

**How can i get a parent element  with padding to resize itself correctly (factoring in the padding) when using the measured height of the dynamic h1 child.**

Comment: Could you provide sample code domenstrating your problem (e.g. a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)) ? It is not very clear the way you describe it...

Comment: Why have the styled parent `<div>` at all, if the `<h1>` is its only child element?

Answer (score 0):

Just make parent div width and height "auto" and then it will resize automatically when h1 resizes

Answer (score 0):

By adding CSS padding, the browser should take care of this automatically, as can be seen in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wuESd/). You should not need to write script to take care of this specifically. In the example below, the black box (div) will dynamically grow vertically as text is added to the red box (h1).

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txt" value="1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" />
<div class="d1">
    <h1 id="h1" class="h1">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.d1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

.h1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Script:

```
$("#txt").change(function () {
    $("#h1").text($("#txt").val());
});
$("#txt").keyup(function() {
    $("#h1").text($("#txt").val());
});
```